# Problèm with incrémentation on Jquery

Tags: jquery, input, jquery-selectors, attributes, each

I have a select

```
    <select class="situation">
 <optgroup label="Situation">
  <option value="1">Married</option>
  <option value="2">Divorced</option>
  <option value="3">single</option>
</optgroup>
</select>
```

Wheb a user choose a option, the value of first index of attribute name is id of situation and the second is position on page.

```
$('.situation').on('change', function(){
    var inputSituation = $( "input.situation" );
    var s = 0;

$( "input.situation" ).each(function() {

            if ($('select.toto option:selected').text() == 'Married'){

                $(this).attr('name', 'situation[2][' + s + ']');
                $(this).attr('name', 'statut[2][' + s + ']');

            }else if($('select.toto option:selected').text() == 'Divorced'){

               $(this).attr('name', 'situation[1][' + s + ']');
               $(this).attr('name', 'statut[1][' + s + ']');

            }/*...*/

        });
       s += 1; 
});
```

My input

```
<div>
<input type="checkbox" name="situation[1][0]" >
<input type="hidden" name="statut[1][0]" >
</div>
```

The value of second index, must to be the same for input, with attribute 'name' situation and 'statut'.

it must be done in this way:

```
<div>
<input type="checkbox" name="situation[1][0]" >
<input type="hidden" name="statut[1][0]" >
</div>

<div>
<input type="checkbox" name="situation[1][1]" >
<input type="hidden" name="statut[1][1]" >
</div>
```

but,  the result is :

```
<div>
<input type="checkbox" name="situation[1][1]" >
<input type="hidden" name="statut[1][2]" >
</div>

<div>
<input type="checkbox" name="situation[1][3]" >
<input type="hidden" name="statut[1][4]" >
</div>
```

Comment: Try to increment `s` in your condition. And put a jsFiddle it will be easier to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

**Javascript**

```
$('.situation').on('change', function(){
    var inputSituation = $( "input.situation" );
    var s = 0;

$( "input.situation" ).each(function() {

            if ($('select.toto option:selected').text() == 'Married'){

                $(this).attr('name', 'situation[2][' + s + ']');
                $(this).attr('name', 'statut[2][' + s + ']');
                s += 1; 
            }else if($('select.toto option:selected').text() == 'Divorced'){

               $(this).attr('name', 'situation[1][' + s + ']');
               $(this).attr('name', 'statut[1][' + s + ']');
               s += 1; 
            }/*...*/

        });

});
```

Because if I have understand you dont want to increment s at every loop but only when one of the condition is true.

Comment: I try this but the result is like this: <div>
<input type="checkbox" name="situation[1][1]" >
<input type="hidden" name="statut[1][2]" >
</div>

<div>
<input type="checkbox" name="situation[1][3]" >
<input type="hidden" name="statut[1][4]" >
</div>

Comment: Can you please provide a jsFiddle.